# SWIFT - Firebase database - Add a key and a value to every user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I have an existing database with example below:

[image]

Now I want to add a new key (say -counts: "") cause I have a new function in app. Is there a function I can add /counts: "" to all users?

I know how to add a key and value to one user:

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let dict = ["dob": ""] as [String : Any]
    REF_CURRENT_USER.updateChildValues(dict as [AnyHashable : Any], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {

        } else {

        }

    })
```

But I have no idea how to add a key and a value to every existing user without manually adding it in the database.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Firebase dynamically adds key: value pairs to the structure as you write them, you don't need to create pre-defined schema in NoSQL databases. So, add code to write that data and it will just be added to the node ongoing as they are updated. The only thing to do is to update your *reading* code to handle cases where that child node may not exist and if it doesn't make the var an empty string. `let counts = snapshot.childSnapshot("counts").value as? String ?? ""`

Answer (score 3):

You can only write/add a value if you know the exact path to the location of that value. So to add a property to each user, you'd:

1. Load all users (so the `/Users` node).
2. [Loop over all child nodes](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+swift+loop+over+children) in that [snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#children).
3. Call `updateChildNodes()` or `setValue()` on the [reference to that child snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#ref), e.g. `childSnapshot.ref.child("counts").setValue(42)`.

Comment: See my comment to the question. I may be misunderstanding?

Comment: No misunderstanding, just a different approach. Backfilling data in case of "schema" changes is equally valid as handling the absence of new properties in code is.

Comment: I never even considered backfilling like that with NoSQL. Interesting approach! ^ for you. lol